# why is my binary search not not working with my array?

Tags: c++, search, binary

trying to learn some basic data structures and algorithms and ive tried to code a basic binary search but it doesn't work unless the input is the same as the middle? can anyone help?

```
void Search(int input) {

    int array[10] = { 0.1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    int first = array[0];
    int last = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);;
    int middle = first + last / 2;

    if (input == middle) {
        cout << "search succesful";
    }
    else if (input > middle) {
        middle + 1;
        Search(input);

    }
    else if (input < middle) {
        middle - 1;
        Search(input);

    }
}

  int main()
    {
     int input;
     cin >> input;
     Search(input);
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated: `int array[10] = {0.1 ...` that conversion is invalid

Comment: Remember that when you call a function, a brand new set of all local variables are created. That's also true for recursive calls. The `middle` variable of the calling function is not the same `middle` variable in the new call.

Comment: You don't have this problem if you implement the search within a loop instead of recursively. Still your implementation provides zero re-usability as data is included in the function itself. Better: Separate data to operate on from the operation itself and provide the former to the latter via parameter.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use recursion than you should also pass the right and left border of array and change them in your if statements. When you do `middle-1` you don't change anything.
Here is binary search implemantation

```
int binarySearch(int nums[], int low, int high, int target)
{
    // Base condition (search space is exhausted)
    if (low > high) {
        return -1;
    }
 
    // find the mid-value in the search space and
    // compares it with the target
 
    int mid = (low + high)/2;    // overflow can happen
    // int mid = low + (high - low)/2;
 
    // Base condition (target value is found)
    if (target == nums[mid]) {
        return mid;
    }
 
    // discard all elements in the right search space,
    // including the middle element
    else if (target < nums[mid]) {
        return binarySearch(nums, low, mid - 1, target);
    }
 
    // discard all elements in the left search space,
    // including the middle element
    else {
        return binarySearch(nums, mid + 1, high, target);
    }
}
```

Comment: As negative indices into the array are meaningless I'd prefer an unsigned type – and from C++ point of view, `size_t` would be the most appropriate type for indices...